# How to start downloading of a dynamically created file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS code (using JQuery), which makes some calculations and provides data as a string. How do I create a file full with this data and suggest the client to download it in my JS code? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server